# Unable to install Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have the issue when trying to install.
I have Laravel version 5.8.33

```
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.8.33, required as 5.8.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.33
].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

D:\xampp7\htdocs\varustame>php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.8.33
```

Comment: kindly update your laravel to 6.~ this issue will be resolved as this package now support version 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last update for this `package` is in laravel `5.7` so you can downgrade your project
to laravel `5.7` and it will run correctly

or install a fresh one

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.7.*"
```

Steps of downgrade:

1. make a backup from your project
2. edit your `composer.json` and make your `laravel` version `5.7`
3. run the command `composer update`

> When you do downgrade may stop of working or you use an option in new version of laravel that it isn't exists in the old version so you can check the upgrade [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade)